# Como descer com um objeto no canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas

Estou criando um projeto do jogo de 1970 parecido com este:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quando peço para o canvas desenhar a bolinha para baixo, ao invés disso ele continua uma linha dessa forma:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue o código:

```
    ball = {
        xStart: 190,
        xEnd: 15,
        yStart: 200,
        yEnd: 15, 
        speed: 1,

        art: function() {
            ctx.fillStyle = "black"
            ctx.fillRect(this.xStart, this.yStart, this.xEnd, this.yEnd);                
        },

        atualiza: function() {
            var tam =2;
            this.yEnd += this.speed; 
        }
    };
```

Pensei em usar o `shift()` mas não tenho muito afinidade com ele e com vetores.
Não achei um problema parecido, se alguem achar me envie aqui, obrigado quem ajudar!!

Comment: `var tam=2;` ta sem utilidade, esqueci de apagar

Comment: Você está usando alguma biblioteca?

Comment: não, javascript puro

Comment: Faltou aumentar o início do y: `this.yStart += this.speed`. Você quer mover, então tem que atualizar o início e fim, não só o fim, se não ele vai aumentar e não mover

Comment: Já tentei, com isso as duas partes vão descer

Comment: E não o que deseja? Tanto o início como o fim mover para baixo

Comment: Isto, mas o rastro que fica pra tras tem que ser desfeito, mas não consigo acessar ele pra apaga

Comment: Antes de atualizar o x e y tenta chamar [`yourCanvasRenderingContext2D.clearRect(this.xStart, this.yStart, this.xEnd, this.yEnd)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/clearRect) passando as coordenadas anteriores e o tamanho